# Convert tibble with species by site data into numeric matrix for vegan::diversity()

Tags: r, matrix, tibble, vegan

I have data in tibble format which looks like this (with 22 more rows and 7 more columns):

```
reprex[1:10,1:7]
# A tibble: 10 x 7
# Groups:   Point, Layer [10]
   Point Layer Lari_deci Quer_rope Pinu_sylv Betu_pend Sorb_aucu
   <chr> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
 1 P03   C     21        17        5         1         0        
 2 P03   U     0         0         0         0         3        
 3 P06   C     3         28        28        0         0        
 4 P07   C     0         3         20        1         1        
 5 P07   U     0         0         0         0         0        
 6 P08   C     0         16        21        0         0        
 7 P08   U     0         0         0         0         0        
 8 P10   C     0         17        44        1         0        
 9 P10   U     0         50        0         0         0        
10 P11   C     0         36        1         0         0
```

```
> dput(reprex[1:10,1:7])
structure(list(Point = c("P03", "P03", "P06", "P07", "P07", "P08", 
"P08", "P10", "P10", "P11"), Layer = c("C", "U", "C", "C", "U", 
"C", "U", "C", "U", "C"), Lari_deci = c("21", "0", "3", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), Quer_rope = c("17", "0", "28", 
"3", "0", "16", "0", "17", "50", "36"), Pinu_sylv = c("5", "0", 
"28", "20", "0", "21", "0", "44", "0", "1"), Betu_pend = c("1", 
"0", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "1", "0", "0"), Sorb_aucu = c("0", 
"3", "0", "1", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), groups = structure(list(Point = c("P03", "P03", "P06", 
"P07", "P07", "P08", "P08", "P10", "P10", "P11"), Layer = c("C", 
"U", "C", "C", "U", "C", "U", "C", "U", "C"), .rows = structure(list(
    1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I want to calculate Simpson's diversity index for each `Point`, considering the two `Layer` levels separately. Since my initial trials attempting this failed, I decided to split the above data into two, by the two levels `C` and `U` and then removing the `Layer` column and converting `Point` to `rownames`.

As a result, I obtained data which was theoretically only numeric (all remaining columns had counts of the corresponding species). But practically, this does not seem to be the case and this is where my problem lies. I then converted the data.frame using `as.matrix` but I still get the following error:
`Error in diversity(., index = "simpson") : input data must be numeric`

```
reprex_C <- reprex %>% filter(Layer == "C") %>% ungroup %>% select(-2) %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var="Point") %>% as.matrix %>% 
  diversity(index = "simpson")
# I would have a similar 'reprex_U' object for Layer == "U".
```

I tried searching for ways to fix this by somehow converting the column values from character to numeric:

```
as.numeric(reprex_C[,1:14])
```

but this loses the row numbers and hence the Point identity. And although `diversity()` now works, it considers all the values as one and calculates just one diversity index for the whole data (as opposed to one value for each row in my original data format).

1. Why is `diversity()` not working with such data? What can I do resolve this?
2. Is there any way to perform `diversity()` without having to split the original data with two `Layer` levels into two separate matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me, that your original dataframe has the numeric columns stored as `chr` instead.  If you coerce them to numeric before you do your split, it should work fine:

```
reprex_C <- reprex %>% 
  mutate(across(Lari_deci:Sorb_aucu,.fns = as.numeric)) %>%
  filter(Layer == "C") %>% ungroup %>% select(-2) %>% 
  column_to_rownames(var="Point") %>% as.matrix %>%
  vegan::diversity(index = "simpson")
```

I'm afraid I'm not familiar enough with diversity to answer your second question.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but I get the same error as before : `Error in diversity(., index = "simpson") : input data must be numeric`

Comment: That's weird, because it works for me.  I see you mentioned that there are 7 additional columns.  Did you adjust the code in line 2 where I put `Lari_deci:Sorb_aucu` to include the first and last of the numeric columns you're dealing with?

Comment: Oh, elementary! Sorry for that, I had missed that step, but yeah now it works. Thank you!

Comment: **vegan** should be tibble-blind, and tibble should work as true blue data frames (please file a bug report in https://github.com/vegandevs/vegan/issues if this fails). The real problem here seems to be that you didn't have numbers but text in your data. An advantage of tibbles is that with tibbles you get information on your variable types, and if you see there `<chr>` you should not expect any numerical method to work.